# query to create table with number of columns equals to number of days in current month in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$month='10';

$year='2012';

$d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);
```

table structure will like

`day1,day2,.......,day31`      (as for october(10) there is 31 days in month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
$month = '10';
$year = '2012';
$d = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `table_name` (';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $d; $i ++)
{
    $sql .= '`day' . $i . '` int(2) DEFAULT NULL';
    if ($i != $d)
        $sql .= ',';
}
$sql .= ') DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1';
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE `table_name` (CREATE TABLE `table_name` (day1 int(2) DEFAULT NULLCREATE TABLE `table_name` (day1 int(2) DEFAULT NULL,day2 int(2) DEFAULT NULLCREATE TABLE `table_name` (day1 int(2) DEFAULT NULL,day2 int(2) DEFAULT NULL,day3 int(2) DEFAULT NULLCREATE TABLE `table_name` (day1 int(2) DEFAULT NULL,day2 int(2) DEFAULT NULL,day3 int(2) DEFAULT NULL,day4 int(2) DEFAULT NULL --------------result is like this

Comment: "CREATE TABLE table_name"  can't be repeated twice because in code it is not used in loop for. Please, check if you use the same code.

Comment: Result is: CREATE TABLE `table_name` (`day1` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day2` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day3` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,   `day4` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day5` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day6` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day7` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day8` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day9` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day10` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day11` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day12` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day13` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day14` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day15` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `day16` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, ..............,  `day31` int(2) DEFAULT NULL
)  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it allows a bit of flexibility:

```
function getQuery($days, $tableName, $columName, $columnLength, $columnType = 'VARCHAR'){
    $query = 'CREATE TABLE ' . $tableName . ' (';

    for($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++){
        $query .= $columName . $i . ' ' . $columnType . '(' . $columnLength . ') NOT NULL, ';
        if($i == $days){
            $query .= $columName . $i . ' ' . $columnType . '(' . $columnLength . ') NOT NULL)';
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
```